# send additonal data with form data via ajax to php

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my js class, I am sending form data via ajax to the php that is fine but I have an array which doesn't belong to that form how can I send it with form data

```
$("#formed").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
 $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data:new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(response) { }
            });
});
```

Now there is array

```
var myList = new Array();
```

It doesn't belong to form but I want to send it making a json array with above ajax call?
**ANY SOLUTION!!!!!**

Comment: It was my mistake to add php tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function `formData.append(name, value);`

```
$("#formed").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
  var data = new FormData(this);
  var myList = [];
  // add your data here
  // to send an array as data you should convert it to the string
  data.append('testField', JSON.stringify(myList));

 $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data:data,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(response) { }
            });
});
```

Comment: and what about append an array?

Comment: is the array a parameter? or It keeps a list of parameters

Comment: You can send an array as a string. on server side you should use `json_decode` to convert the text to php array

Comment: and when i AM sending server side list is empty

Comment: `var form = $(this);
  var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  data.append('colorListSmall', JSON.stringify(smallColorArray));
    $colorListSmall= str_replace('\n', '', $_POST['colorListSmall']);
    $colorListSmall= rtrim($colorListSmall, ',');
    $json_colorListSmall = json_decode($colorListSmall, true);
`

Comment: This is how I did it

Comment: I made a mistake caused by copy&past. I fixed it

Comment: Sorry when i append the array i get null in php

Comment: log the $_POST with print_r and check if  there is any data in $_POST

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what do u mean

Comment: No there is no data in $_POST

Comment: open chorom Devtools and check the request in network tab. is there any data?